# Boilerplate/template keeps showing the same contents of App.Js page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hot-reload, react-boilerplate

So I created a new React App and tried editting the default template/boilerplate file but unfortunately, the page is not reloading despite changing the contents of the app.js 
[image: new contents from the App.js]

I did a manual reload and got this: 
[image: After changing the default app.js boilerplate]

What have I done so far?

Deleted node_modules and re-installed it 
Run npm start
npm update 
Invalidated caches and Restart ( I use Webstorm )

and the hot reload seems not to work.

I´m loosing some  hairs already and would appreciate if someone can just point me in the right direction. I know this could be a simple fix but pardon my ignorance as am just starting into the wonderful world of React.

All tips would be welcomed

Edit:
This is the error message that pops up in the terminal after punching Npm start

[image: Error in the terminal]

Comment: Can you please share the image of the terminal where you hit the `npm start` command?

Comment: Hi @AniketKolekar I just updated my question with the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it should be reloading. Maybe it's a caching issue? Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to hard reload.

Or pull it up in an incognito browser.